# Service Fabric Load Balancer not forwarding traffic correctly

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-load-balancer

I have a ASP.NET website that connects to a set of WCF services in a service fabric cluster behind an internal load balancer. The service connection strings in the website points to the address of the internal load balancer. There are three nodes in the cluster and three copies of backend services.

When I manually restart one of the node, I find that the website failed to load correctly because the load balancer seems to be still forwarding requests to the service in the restarting node. Shouldn't the load balancer forward requests to the two other available services? Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: cross posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38df820d-2bf6-43f2-9f36-8d319f45afe1/service-fabric-load-balancer-not-forwarding-traffic-correctly?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Comment: Can you share your LB configuration? Did you create Inbound NAT rule to forward traffic or created LB rules? Does the probe listening on the same port as that of your application?

Comment: @msrini-MSIT Thanks for the reply. I have probes on the same port as my application. But i couldn't get the probe to work if its UDP. I wonder if the probing operation is like doing a telnet on the port?

Comment: Or do i need to write code to handle the probing requests?

Comment: There are no UDP probes available at this point. Only TCP or HTTP probes. In Standard SKU you will have HTTPS probes as well.

Comment: If you choose TCP probe, the probing is successful if the 3 way handshake is successful.